# Performing full text search on more than one field from model (Django 2.1)

Tags: django

I want to perform full text search on two fields from my model. Here is my current code:

```
if 'keyword' in request.GET:
    search_term = request.GET['keyword']
    vector = SearchVector('Title', weight='A') + SearchVector('Content', weight='B')
    articles = articles.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity(vector, search_term),).filter(similarity__gt=0.01).order_by('-similarity')
```

This code returns the error message

```
function similarity(tsvector, unknown) does not exist
```

I assume this is because I am not combining the fields correctly because when I just put one single field in place of `vector`, it works fine. If the pg_trgm extension wasn't installed properly, trigram search wouldn't work on one field, right? What's the proper way of searching in more than one field?

Comment: Better way would be to use Q object: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: @Ahtisham you can't perform a full text search using just Q. The OP is correct, and the answer is given below.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm so confused. So Q isn't the solution? Can you please elaborate on how to properly do a full text search on more than 1 field? Thanks in advance

Comment: @dirkgroten I know the issue isn't that pg_trgm isn't installed because the trigram search works when there is only one field; it only doesn't work when I try to combine fields, so I assumed that I'm combining them wrong. If I just put one single field in place of "vector", it works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misread your question, the error shows you have `similarity` function installed, but says you can't use a search vector with the `similarity` function. Since you want to search for patterns with a similarity higher than a threshold, you can calculate the similarity on each field separately and return the maximum value. You can't combine them with a rank. Try this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

articles.annotate(
    similarity=Greatest(
         TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), 
         TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term)
    )).filter(similarity__gte=0.1).order_by('-similarity')
```

If you want to give a higher weight to 'Title', you can just wrap with a math function to add weight instead of using `Greatest`:

```
A = 1.0; B = 0.4
articles.annotate(
    similarity=(A/(A+B) * TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term) 
               + B/(A+B) * TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))
    ).filter(similarity__gte=0.1).order_by('-similarity')
```

Note that the latter will decrease the similarity value if there's a good match in 'Title' and no match in 'Content' with respect to `Greatest`, so you probably want to set the threshold lower.

Note2: similarity looks at the full strings, so if you have a long piece of text ('Content') and just one keyword to search, similarity is going to return 0 even if the keyword is contained in the 'Content'. For full-text search, you're better off using `SearchRank` together with `SearchVector`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration! I tried these solutions. The first one returns error ("Greatest" is not defined"). Is there a library for this? The second one has no error message but simply returns everything in my database in the order set in the database

Comment: I don't know why the second method would return all objects, you'd need to check the individual similarities for 'Title' and 'Content' separately (use `.values('similarity')` to list the values in your console).

Comment: I added the import and now both solutions return everything in my database in the order set in the database. I think something is wrong with my 2nd field. I will look into it and get back to you. Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: If the query returns nothing or everything, try adjusting the similarity threshold. 0.03 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm believe need to install the `pg_trgm` extension in your database. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity) indicate that it's necessary to use those functions.

[Create an empty migration and use the following operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#django.contrib.postgres.operations.TrigramExtension):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension

operations = [TrigramExtension()]
```

Comment: I have installed pg_trgm; the trigram search works otherwise. I just don't know how to combine 2 fields into one expression